# Why does Bing Webmaster Tools tell me that my h1 tag is missing?

Tags: seo, html, search-engine-indexing, bing, h1

Here is a snippet of code from my `index.htm` page. The `h1` tag is there, so why isn't Bing recognizing it?

```
<body class="designview landing-page sidebar-collapse"> 

    <script>
    document.body.className = document.body.className.replace("designview", "");
    //document.getElementByTagName("body")[0].removeClass("designview");
    </script>
    
    <div class="template-header">
    <!-- #BeginEditable "header" --> 
    
    <!--webbot bot="Include" tag="BODY" u-include="Library/shared/header.htm" -->  
    <!-- #EndEditable --> 
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="template-showcase">
    <!-- #BeginEditable "showcase" -->
    

<div class="page-header header-filter" data-parallax="true" style="background-image: url('Site/themed-images/backgrounds/Blacewood-inside.jpg')">
    <div class="container" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="style1">
          <div class="brand text-center">
            <h1>here is the tag text</h1>
          </div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters.  1) What error do you get from Bing, specifically?  2) It is possible that your html is broken.  Have you tested it ?  3) Please post your complete html that reproduces the problem here.   Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)